# повышенное потребление памяти composer

Tags: php, composer, утечка-памяти

При запуске composer --profile update, сам composer показывает, что потребляет не много памяти (`[138.1MB/207.55s] Importing tag v1.6.1-patch5188 (1.6.1.0-patch5188`), но htop показывает, что процесс php ./composer.phar потребляет гораздо больше (более 8Гб пямяти). Причем, если запускаю на машине, на которой меньше 8Гб, то процесс прерывается с ошибкой `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of _______ bytes exhausted (tried to allocate __ bytes)`
А где памяти хватает вывод в конце: `[1156.8MB/527.07s] Memory usage: 1156.83MB (peak: 6140.88MB), time: 527.07s`

---

Вопрос: Почему нужно так много памяти? Это нормально? Можно как-то снизить требования?
PS Субъективно кажется что больше всего памяти потребляется после импорта всех тагов... Может не управлять пакетами js через composer-bower-assest вообще? ручками их ставить...

---

PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21

php.ini: memory_limit = -1

composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
    "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "^2.0.6",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "^2.0.6",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "^2.0.6",
        "yiisoft/yii2-authclient": "^2.0.0",
        "dektrium/yii2-user": "~0.9.6",
        "fxp/composer-asset-plugin": "^1.2",
        "yiisoft/yii2-imagine": "~2.1.0",
        "bower-asset/ng-flow": "^2.7",
        "flowjs/flow-php-server": "^1.0",
        "yii2mod/yii2-comments": "^1.9",
        "bower-asset/angular-sanitize": "^1.6"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800,
        "fxp-asset.installer-paths": {
            "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
            "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": "php init --env=Development --overwrite=n"
    }
}
```

Comment: 8гб какой памяти? Резиднтной? Виртуальной?

Comment: И той, и той VIRT больше чем RES Мб на 500...